# How can I pass multi-line input (stdin) into a command I'm executing in my Makefile?

Tags: makefile, stdin

I'm writing a dead simple Makefile to be used with GHCi and gedit. Essentially, I define a module to load, and a function (along with its parameters) to call/test. The Makefile would need to execute GHCi and then pass the necessary commands into it. I tried piping with `echo`, and it worked in a normal shell, but fails due to the way `make` handles whitespace, strings & formatting. It feeds the whole thing as as one single line, rather than individual lines of input. On top of that, it is a bit messy.

```
# Sorry if backslashes are messed up do to tabs...
module   = somemodule
function = somefunction
params = 5 "Hello"

default: *.hs
    echo                \
        :l $(module)        \
                    \
        $(function) $(params)   \
        | ghci
```

How could I acheive this *cleanly* and *elegantly*? :)

Comment: How does it fail? How do you know that the cause is whitespace, strings & formatting? What's wrong with `echo :l $(module) $(function) $(params) | ghci`?

Comment: @Beta The main issue is that `:l $(module)` and `$(function) $(params)` need to be two seperate lines (since they need to be interactively evaluated _seperately_ by GHCi), and this is feeding them as one. Other methods I've tried to explicitly seperate them causes them to be considered to be seperate commands. I'll add this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using two separate `echo` commands?

```
( echo ":l $(module)"; echo "$(function) $(params)" ) | ghci
```

Answer (score 1):

An upcoming version of GNU Make will have a [`$(file)` function](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/doc/make.texi?root=make&r1=1.76&r2=1.77) to aid in similar situations, though perhaps not quite this one.

In lieu of that, the basic approach is to have the newlines not be newlines at the critical moment:

```
define boilerplate
:l $(module)
$(function) $(params)
endef

define newline


endef

default: *.hs
    echo '$(subst $(newline),|,$(boilerplate))' | tr '|' '\n' | ghci
```

(The source text for that `$(newline)` definition contains two empty lines, as `define` eats one trailing newline before the `endef`.)

If you can't assume GNU Make and therefore don't have `subst` or `define`, you can write the `|`-encoded newlines directly in the echo command:

```
default: *.hs
    echo ':l $(module)|$(function) $(params)' | tr '|' '\n' | ghci
```

...at which point it's just a matter of taste whether this is better or worse than Idelic's subshell suggestion.